# Jar connect with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I' new at Java.

I finished my Java program with Netbeans that connects with mysql server using `JDBC (jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory";)` and built the Jar.

When I ran the jar, It seems wont connect the mysql, what should I do? Should I change localhost to my computer IP?

Thanks

Comment: More detail needed here.  What do you mean it "won't connect" - what error message are you getting?  Is it finding the database but not connecting or is it failing to find the database, for example.

Comment: It's working if the jar ran on the server computer(connected to db). but when I copy the jar file to other computer in the same network, It won't connect.

Comment: I have solved this problem. So I should copy the connector jar to other computer too. Does anyone here know how to build those jars within 1 jar? So I need no to copy connector jar

Answer (score 0):

Do you require a user and password?  If so you might need to add it to the connection string like so:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory?user=bandi&password=yourpass
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it run in netbeans if complied? if yes, it seem you don't switch on the database server when running the .jar file. try opening the mysql server first and then run the application. Another case, if it's not working during compliation in netbeans, it means you have issues in you connection and or try to switch off your firewall or antivirus.

Comment: My server is always on sir but the jar on other computer didnt get any data

Answer (score 0):

The first probable problem is the URL you are using:

which should be like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://[my-sql-server-ip]:3306/inventory
```

typically for the small applications you can put the server-ip and server-port in a .properties file near your jar file. If you don't want to have this file, you can have a very simple GUI form at the start up of your application to get the server-ip and server-port from the user. (Do not make to hard if this is not an application for an end-user. Get the input simply using JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog(...) and make your connection URL dynamically based on the user's input.)

If the server-ip is not the problem, typically the second problem is that the connector jar file for my-sql is not in the class path of your application.

There are two workarounds:

1. The ugly but simple way: download the source files for the my-sql connector from the my-sql's site and put the whole source codes in your application, and then you can build up a Big Fatty jar file which contains the connector's classes for my-sql.

This is not the experts choice, because the philosophy of JDBC is:
Do not depend your database layer codes to a specific database, and when you inject the source of the my-sql connector in your project, you are so coupled to that. Also if you want to update the my-sql connector for your project you have to recompile your project. I can not count the shortages of this solution, you can read about it yourself.

2. The better way: is to put a manifest in you project (then it will be in your output jar file) to declare the class path dependencies. Then create a folder near to your output jar file which contains the the connector and probably other dependencies for your project.

For example in a root folder:

```
root-folder
+ [your output jar name].jar
+ [lib folder name]
   +  mysql-connector-java-[your version].jar
```

and the entries for the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: [lib folder name]/mysql-connector-java-[your version].jar
Main-Class: [fully qualified package and class name without .java to your main class]
```

for example:

```
Main-Class: com.staefi.main.App
```

Which App.java is the class with the main method to start the program.

Another tip is to **put the MANIFEST.MF file in the root of src folder in your project inside the META-INF folder**. For example:

```
src
+ META-INF
  + MANIFEST.MF
+ [your packages start here]
```

And finally you can zip the ROOT-FOLDER to create a portable output of your project and dependencies.

Also another way is to create a bat/sh file to maintain the class path and the execution of your jar file, but it is so similar to the above way. If were you I wouldn't inject the connector's classes in my output jar file.

Good Luck.